# Control flickers while drawing in .Net Compact Framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I have a control which draws some items on a bitmap.

I am using the Microsoft gesture library to scroll and pan the bitmap.

While doing panning or scrolling my bitmap flickers a lot.

I am drawing just a portion of bitmap in `OnPaint` method depending on scroll/panned cordinates.

Following is the sample code:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            using (Graphics g = e.Graphics)
            {
                if (!_painted)
                {
                    // drawing items first time
                    InitilizeBitmap(g);                 
                    _painted = true;
                }           

                Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(0, _bitmapLocation.Y, ClientRectangle.Width, ClientRectangle.Height);
                using (Graphics gCached = Graphics.FromImage(_cachedBitmap))
                {
                    gCached.Clear(BackColor);
                    gCached.DrawImage(_bmpControl, 0, 0, rec, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                }

                g.DrawImage(_cachedBitmap, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Is there a way to avoid flickering ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're only using 1 buffer, so draw operations appear immediately. What you need is page flipping/double buffering.

What you want to do is set up a new graphics object that you do all your drawing on, and then draw the finished object when it's done. This should eliminate any flickering because the bitmap that is facing the screen is only updated once, and all in one go.

Comment: How can I draw some portion of a bitmap on another bitmap ?

Comment: Same way as you currently are. Set up a graphics object for the new bitmap.